# Pop up a warning for answers at low quality, off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, low-quality-posts

We should have a warning popup

> **Attention!** Please don't answer low quality or [*off-topic*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions. Try to salvage the problems with the question first by editing, or flag/close vote it appropriately.

or the better version (adopted from [@poke's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361133/8242698))

> This question has currently a negative score and/or multiple close votes. Before investing time in your answer, please *verify that the question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*, so your effort is not wasted and so that we do not encourage bad questions by answering them anyway.
>
> If you believe the question is on-topic and has its merit, consider leaving a comment on the question first to explain your reasoning.

when an answer to a question—which had received a significant number of downvotes or already more than 3 close votes—is about to be posted.

This could help to reduce misconceptions of Stack Overflow, that you'll get an answer, no matter how bad your question is.

---

**Update:**

I've just noticed that the

- [<kbd>Explainer ●</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer)
- [<kbd>Refiner ●</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner)
- [<kbd>Illuminator ●</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator)

badges are relevant. Just worth mentioning.

These badges actively support and encourage the behavior I'm trying to enforce with that warning:

1st care to salvage the OPs problems, then answer (maybe).

Comment: _"A wooden pole a day, keeps the help vampire away!" (- v. Helsing)_ :-)

Comment: 'you'll get an answer at Stack Overflow, no matter how bad your question is'... that ship's sailed:(   Why not post a bad question?  At best, you get an answer to copy out quickly, at worst, other SO users waste time and effort closing/deleting it but, hey, that's someone else's life wasted, so why give a PHP about that?

Comment: @Martin As the doctor said ... And roomba's life will get easier too ;-)

Comment: The cucmbers who answer bad questions for rep won't care about any popup, other than see it as an extra nag-click;(

Comment: @Martin _"that ship's sailed ..."_ Not to mention I never was Joel's [seal driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzu3fKtl-04).

Comment: What should we call a significant number of downvotes? Five? Seven?

Comment: @E_net4 Yeah, 6-8 should be considered _significant_.

Comment: If we're already confident enough at 3 close votes (or 6-8 downvotes) that the question shouldn't be answered, with enough confidence to tell people not to post answers, then *why are they even able to post answers*?  If we're already confident that the question shouldn't be answered, don't let them answer it.

Comment: @Servy I'm trying to address the _grey area_, that deserves a warning, not denial of answer. The latter is what 5 close votes agreed are for.

Comment: @user0042 But if we're honestly not sufficiently sure if the question is problematic, then why are we telling people not to answer the question?

Comment: @Servy what's worse. We let them answer even if the question is closed ... if they started typing soon enough - because we don't want the effort they spent writing their answer go to waste too soon (or ever, if the question slips through the second round of janitorial duties)

Comment: There's already a badge to encourage answering low scored questions... https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal

Comment: the question isn't off-topic until it's closed as such. So the message would need to be changed at least. otherwise, good idea: you have been warned, don't complain if your answers get downvotes :)

Comment: In my experience, it's pretty common to see a decent, on-topic, useful question get voted way down because an early viewer apparently misread the question and downvoted, and then the next viewers see the negative score, biasing them toward misreading the question in the same way, and causing them to pile on with downvotes.  This is especially common with beginner questions.  I don't think it's appropriate to discourage the thoughtful folks who look past the negative scores and provide quality answers to questions that will help future readers.

Comment: If a question is genuinely of very low quality, it should be literally impossible to answer it. This also applies to many (but certainly not all) off-topic questions (esp. ones lacking the relevant source code, error messages, and so on). For the remainder, your suggestion doesn't seem to amount to much more than slightly lowering the bar for when we close questions. The rationale you give for this seems somewhat naive. If users *really* wanted to be freed from such misconceptions, they could just visit the help centre - but we all know that 90% of them have no interest in ever doing that.

Comment: _"it should be literally impossible to answer it"_ Yes, but people love to try anyways, either assuming they know what's going on, or to leave "pointers" and "hints".

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy the early downvotes are also often a part of the process of salvaging a question, so it's certainly possible that a question gets downvotes because some part of it is unclear, but then retains those downvotes even after clarification. Implementing something that makes salvaging questions even harder sounds like a monumentally bad idea.

Comment: @JoshCaswell. My experience of working the review queues strongly suggests otherwise. Users are overwhelmingly more likely to answer easily comprehended questions (many of them dups), because they know it will earn them rep more quickly. Extracting sense out of a poor question takes more time and effort, and usually earns less rep.

Comment: The wording can use an adjustment. "This question has been flagged as being potentially off-topic and is under review. Please review the question to make sure it is on-topic prior to answering." would be better in my opinion.

Comment: I like it for the simple reason that I often run into people whose answers I comment on for this exact reason, reply with "we're here to help everyone with their problems" this feature will have the potential to help fight/avoid this

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972362/program-runs-differently-for-first-and-second-executions-why/47972624#47972624) is a counterexample. Even though from its very first iteration on, the question contained code and a clear problem description. Despite that there are no less than **four** close votes for "... must contain code and a problem description..." Not one of the close-voters retracted their vote.

Comment: @Wingblade: I don't understand your response.  How do a bunch of early downvotes help "salvage" a perfectly good question?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy They don't help, but they are a part of the process. E.g. a question may receive downvotes for appearing unclear, which it may retain even after receiving an edit for clarification.

Comment: very similar proposal targeting duplicates: [Could: “Possible duplicate of..” be given prominence for answering users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352450/839601)

Comment: @usr2564301 One single counterexample doesn't really argue effectively against this. The whole point is that it's _just a suggestion_ to the answerer. _Of course_ there will be times that someone can provide a good answer even if the question is badly received. Can you demonstrate that those are more common than the opposite?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: there are two conflicting approaches in play: trigger-happy close voters who do not retract their vote even after a post has successfully been edited in shape, and rep-hunter/"see how smart I am" answerers who will happily answer *anything*. There is a system in place that prohibits answering bad questions: it's "On hold", a consensus of five users (or a single Gold Badge holder). There is also already a warning for "possibly a bad question": downvotes and pending close votes. A (minor) peeve of mine is that unjustified or obsoleted downvotes can be counteracted with an upvote...

Comment: ... but unjustified or obsoleted *close votes* cannot. That means such a warning will pop up practically forever on an initially badly received question.

Comment: @usr2564301 IMO a minor _"harm"_ compared to the majority of cases these questions where the _initial receipt_ was correct.

Comment: @usr2564301: FYI: There's no such thing as "retracting" a close vote. Once you've made a close vote, it's done; the only thing you could do is wait until the question is closed and then vote to reopen.

Comment: @NicolBolas _"There's no such thing as "retracting" a close vote"_ Of course you can retract your close vote as long the question isn't put [on hold].

Comment: @usr2564301 As mentioned that's only possible as long the question wasn't put [on hold] already. After this point, the only option is to vote for reopening.

Comment: @BoogaRoo 100+ upvotes on request to [Get rid of the Reversal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277576/839601) suggest that many find behavior it incentivizes not really good for the site purposes

Answer (score 26):

I like the spirit, but I don't think it'll be very successful, for the simple fact that **a question's state is always fluid**.  Depending on what the question is, it can be edited into shape to improve readability or its reception, and voting can always be reversed or overcome.

Not just this, but what one group of people [think is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360987/1079354) may not *actually* be off-topic, which means the message is a false positive, and a misleading one at that.  This situation should be rare, but is relatively uncommon in practice.

Further, I think you misconstrue the point of close voting.  Except for every question that is *truly* off-topic, a question can be edited into shape to make it better.

I get what you're trying to accomplish, but I fear it'll undermine more than it'll actually fix.

Comment: Relatively common, or relatively uncommon?

Comment: @TinyGiant:  Relatively uncommon.  It doesn't happen all that much but it's a thing we should be aware of and prepared for.

Comment: Ok, it just seemed off due to the first part of the sentence. _"This situation should be rare, but is relatively uncommon in practice."_ reads as "This should be rare, and is" to me. Personally, I see incorrect closures on the regular, which is also one of the reasons I have been participating less and less over the past while. At one point I was using the filter "[javascript]; too broad" in the close vote queue to find interesting questions to answer.

Comment: I see incorrect closures far too often for my tastes too @TinyGiant.  Right now I'm trying to make sense of it all.  It does demotivate, I don't dispute that.

Answer (score 13):

> This question has currently a negative score and/or multiple close votes. Before investing time in your answer, please *verify that the question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*, so your effort is not wasted and so that we do not encourage bad questions by answering them anyway.
>
> If you believe the question is on-topic and has its merit, consider leaving a comment on the question first to explain the your reasoning.

This wording [assumes good faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Assume_good_faith) in regards to the question and won’t make it sound as if the downvotes or close votes have already decided about the outcome. As others mentioned in the comments, none of that is a clear sign that a question is actually off-topic or bad.

However, it could be an indicator, so we should give answerers the heads-up that they might be wasting their effort. By asking them to verify that the question is actually on-topic, we are actively giving them an actual *benefit* for thinking about it.

In addition, we also explain what they should do to reverse the direction the question is heading, by leaving a comment, possibly convincing others.

Answer (score 5):

Providing a warning upfront may result in an opposite reaction - i.e. rushing a half-finished answer before the question is closed, and ninja-editing it later. The question obviously appears on-topic to a member who is answering it, even if other members find it off-topic, so he is likely to disregard the warning.

On the other hand, an encouragement to edit the question with multiple close votes would be a good idea once the answer has been posted, because the member who has just answered the question is likely to have a better insight into why the question should be on-topic than the members who voted to close.

Duplicates should be treated separately, though. I think it would be a good idea to offer a window with a list of potential duplicates to a person answering the question, in a similar way to how it is done when you ask a question. This should help closing "easy questions" as duplicates in situations when it's harder to find a duplicate than to type up a new answer.

Comment: This would mainly be helpful for users who _do not_ have a firm grasp on the subtleties of Stack Overflow's topicality. Sure, if I got this warning when I was answering a question, i would smirk and keep going, but it's not meant for me. No need for anyone to rush either. You can still submit an answer within 24 hours of initial closure if you loaded the question before it was closed.

Comment: @TinyGiant If a user does not have a firm grasp on the subtleties of Stack Overflow's topicality, he'd have hard time "salvaging the question by editing or commenting," as suggested by OP's warning.

Comment: Well at least they might think twice about answering a potentially off-topic question.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think this could be addressed by letting everybody see the number of close votes on the question, regardless of their reputation.

Comment: That would probably just end up with a lot of meta complaints about close votes, instead of closed qhestions. The idea has been explored in the past, but maybe it should be looked at again.

Answer (score -13):

I would think either answering such questions should be disabled altogether or the answers should be allowed. I see no point in "middle ground" where we allow answers but attach warnings when placing them.

Comment: that's why the questions are closed after a while. But as long as they're open, anything goes, including a surprisingly good answer that "reverses" the thread.

Comment: People erroneously cast close votes and downvotes on reasonable questions all time. I would be fairly peeved if I was prevented from answering a reasonable on-topic question because three well-meaning but uneducated users decided to downvote / vote to close the question.

Comment: There's value to middle ground if it's used to raise the bar for answers. If only high-rep users are allowed to answer a young question on its way to being closed, that'll discourage the people who should know better, and leave only folks with enough invested in the site that they should respond well to social pressures (or who are genuinely identifying that the question was misinterpreted by early close voters, or that the question has been edited in a manner that improves it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy *If only high-rep users are allowed to answer a young question on its way to being closed* Sometimes those users earned their reputation by answering off-topic questions. (See the FGITW problem)