# Should answers to trivial questions be avoided?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011015/basic-pre-course-java-task-for-beginner-student) which was promptly downvoted. This led me wondering: Should trivial questions be ignored? Clearly if you're getting downvoted, that means someone disagrees with your answer.
<sub>(this is my first meta post; tell me if I'm not doing it right)</sub>

Image of question and answer (as it has been closed and may not be visible to all):

[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/pop-up-a-warning-for-answers-at-low-quality-off-topic-questions

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Comment: That is not a trivial question; it is not even a question at all

Comment: when there's -22 votes to a question, expect trouble when answering (even if maybe there were only 5 ot 6 downvotes when you answered)

Comment: *Clearly if you're getting downvoted, that means someone disagrees with your answer.* No, not really. In the tooltip it says *This answer is not useful*. An answer can be correct and I can agree with it, still find it not useful for future visitors.

Comment: That's not even a question, so "answering" it is meaningless. But if you're going to answer terrible questions, your answers need to be much, _much_ better than usual to convince other people that the original post has some merit. If you reply to low quality posts with similar low quality, then you're just creating a bigger pile, and not really helping anything, are you?

Comment: I'm still far from convinced that the question is not a troll...

Comment: I can't believe the OP looked at the draft of that question and decided that what it needed was the `coding-style` tag.

Comment: Hard to imagine that you don't already know the answer.  Consider that the basic problem with the answer is that it just did not take the question seriously.  Clearly this user needs a *lot* of help to learn programming basics.  You did not offer that kind of help.  It is like somebody yelling "help me, I broke my leg".  And you giving him a Band-Aid and walked away.  How you *could* help is not obvious, I don't think it can be done, but that's your burden to figure out when you post an answer.

Comment: @MartinJames: be that as it may, the motivation behind the original SO question has no relevance to this meta question; rather only the quality of the question and answer matter.

Comment: If you have to guess the language and what the OP is asking then this is clearly something that should be closed until clarified. Though tbh even if the question was unambiguously Javascript and they clearly stated they were asking how to implement that function I doubt the Q would have survived.

Comment: @ericw31415: just for completeness. If you can reasably *suspect* a question is a clear duplicate, and a trivial search shows you it *is*, would you still answer? Because when I see that – and the question has already been marked as a possible dup – I have a hard time deciding whether or not to downvote any and all answers for being "not useful".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre have you ever seen such a thing on Python tag (outside of meta-effect)? 22 downvotes seems insane, maybe our mods clear them away faster than it can get to than point compared to JS.

Comment: not python bad questions go down to -7 after what they're closed, and after closure downvotes have a tendency to calm down

Comment: @gnat Trivial questions and off-topic questions are quite different.

Comment: @ericw31415: true they are different categories, but oftentimes a question is both. You yourself stated that you flagged the question that brought about this meta discussion for closure, meaning that you felt it was off-topic, along with many other members of this site.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with trivial questions or their answers. The problem is with questions that's basically just a request for code (trivial or not) that have no future value. In this case, if they don't know the basic syntax, they should be reading a book or taking a course - [so] is not a good place to learn a language from scratch. If, on the other hand, they can't figure out the logic, giving them the code doesn't teach them anything and probably does more harm than good.

Comment: That particular "question" is pretty-well unsalvagable. But sometimes poor questions can be improved to the point where it _is_ worthwhile to answer them. Sometimes that can be done by prompting the OP via comments, but if the OP's English skills are poor you may need to assist them by editing the question yourself.

Answer (score 47):

First full disclosure: I'm an involved party in this question, as I'm one of several who down-voted the original poster's Stack Overflow answer, but I'm the only one who left a comment.

It is relevant that the question was not just low-quality, but extremely low quality, but that's not the main reason that I downvoted the answer, since we all have seen some simply amazing answers to seemingly trivial questions, but not here.

The real reason for my downvote was that the answer was little more than a code dump with no explanation whatsoever, and that in my book does warrant a downvote. In my mind, the whole benefit of Q/A is how well it should help future visitors to this site with similar problems. If the question is of such low quality that it does not help future visitors, close it, don't answer it, but if you do answer it, it still needs to be a good answer, and the merits of the answer are still judged the same as any other answer.

In fact, as Josh Caswell mentioned in comment, answers to such trivial questions should be *much* better than the average answer, if only to convince members to not close and delete the question and to give that particular Q/A some merit and benefit to the community.

Comment: I will sometimes give a trivial answer to a trivial question in the hope of eliciting a supplementary question that explains what the user's real problem is, of the kind "yes, I know that, but what I really meant to ask was X".

Comment: @MichaelKay: I sometimes give a Community Wiki answer to weak and unclear questions since this way, all can contribute to the answer and improve it when/if the question improves and becomes clearer.

Comment: @MichaelKay: that's one of my guilty pleasures: giving a literal answer. It's a cruel thing to do, I know.

Comment: @usr2564301: or a [literal comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035257/insert-data-into-different-subclasses-using-for-loop-in-java#comment83040455_48035257)

Comment: Once you figure it out all questions are trivial

Comment: @Pomagranite: ah but to reach that lofty height, one must reach full SO enlightenment

Answer (score 22):

Trivial questions certainly deserve answers in my opinion. Some of the most read questions are pretty trivial, and sometimes only a few lines long.

Note, however, that both asking and answering a trivial question is very hard.

You may ask a trivial question if:

- It's broadly applicable (not overly localized)
- It's not based on a typo or simple misconception (those can be answered in the comments, and closed as off-topic)
- It's not a duplicate (very important! Most trivial questions have been asked and answered before)
- It's not overly trivial (e.g. how do I set a variable in my language-> wrong, how do I remove the first element of an array in my language-> right). Questions about elemental syntax require more of a tutorial than an answer, and therefore aren't really suitable for the site
- It's specific. The OP should have a single problem, and the rest of the code should work.

When answering a question that meets all these criteria (after checking for duplicates), make sure to post a thorough answer. Since the answer is trivial, a lot of people can probably answer it. Don't just state the obvious in a short section of code, but try to explain why and how, and evaluate multiple possibilities if there are a finite number of plausible answers.

Don't answer a question that should be closed! That sometimes keeps the roomba from auto-deleting it, sends a mixed message, and encourages the OP to post more similar questions (because he got his answer).

---

Let's take the current question:

1. It's overly localized. Instead of asking "how do I multiply numbers", it specifically asks to multiply an input by 10, and then return the value.
2. It's not specific. OPs sample code doesn't return values, so you will have to explain returning values too.
3. It's base syntax, which makes for bad questions.
4. It probably is a dupe.
5. It's unclear. You assume OP means javascript because of the syntax in his question, but he might as well want a java answer but just doesn't know how to provide the relevant java sample code.

Each one of those reasons is a possible reason to close and not answer the question. All these things combined make the question of very low quality, and thus this question should be left downvoted, closed and unanswered.

Comment: **Don't answer a question that should be closed!** This is the bit I wish more people followed.

Comment: @TemporalWolf in a perfect world everything would be blackor white and we would all agree on what should and should not be closed. Unfortunately that is not the case, so I agree with the sentiment, but the reality is much more messy.

Comment: Minor thing: IIRC "too localized" was removed as a close reason.

Comment: @jrh that's certainly true, but questions shouldn't be really trivial _and_ really localized in my opinion. However, one could say this question, for example, could be edited to be less localized, so that shouldn't be the sole reason to close it

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Right, it was just a nitpick I mentioned because you said "... each one of those reasons is a possible reason to close."

Comment: "*how do I remove the first element of an array in my language*" is awfully close to asking for an array tutorial, or even worse: asking for the docs of array methods, which is an off-topic resource request. I think most basic/trivial questions are looking for tutorials, but that's not necessarily a bad thing if those resources are lacking on the web.

Comment: @Bergi I mean questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4426663), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19544452) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457453). All received a high amount of views and upvotes while being trivial, and are good contributions to the site imo. Most trivial questions can be solved by reading the docs, but having a short how-to for a single specific task that's easily findable with example code is a good thing, and often lacks in the docs.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yeah, I just think that "How do I use variables" or "How to multiply numbers" are of similar triviality. (OK, maybe arrays - most people's first data structures - are a bit more advanced, though it depends on the language)

Comment: @Bergi there's a difference in my opinion between base syntax (defining variables, writing functions, basic mathematical operators that are the same for most languages) and more language specific and advanced functions. After switching to a language I haven't used in a while, I often find myself thinking _did this one have a built-in array shift function?_, but never thinking about variable definition and basic operators.  Anyway, you will find many highly upvoted questions considering trivialities with arrays, but none (afaik) with addition/multiplication.

Comment: @Bergi "...is awfully close to asking for an array tutorial, or even worse: asking for the docs of array methods" I can't agree with you on that one, the OP in that case is looking for a specific answer, not something that might be buried in something that is 90% irrelevant information. Besides, IIRC off site resource requests are discouraged only because they might disappear. I don't understand what the problem is with posting context-specific information from the docs in the answerer's own words. All knowledge on this site comes from some book/docs/blog somewhere, after all.

Answer (score 3):

> Should trivial questions be ignored?

No. But answering is the wrong reaction. You can tell the OP what's wrong in a comment, and flag that question to be closed properly.

Comment: I downvoted+flagged+answered.

Comment: @ericw31415 As mentioned: "downvote + flag + **comment**" is the right course of action.

Comment: @ericw31415 Answering and flagging for closure go in opposite directions. Do only **one** of those actions.

Comment: there's also probably a duplicate covering the subject.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre only one?

Comment: -1 bevause this answer assumes that all trivial questions are off-topic or even worthy of downvoting. All that is required of such questions that they are clear, reasonably scoped, and well defined. There's a vast number of trivial questions out there that ha e been very helpful to many people, because what is trivial to someone versed in a language may be ellusive to those who are not.

Comment: _(apparently I can't type on a phone)_

Comment: @TinyGiant You're missing "researched" in your list. Sad thing is too many users are way to lenient on that part.

Comment: @Tom research only really counts if the answer already exists on Stack Overflow. If it does, close it as a dupe. If it doesn't, then research doesn't _really_ matter as much as some people would like to think it does. I mean yeah, it makes us feel warm and fuzzy to see that the author did some research, but ultimately it doesn't add anything to the question for future readers, or answerers for that matter (above and beyond that fuzzy feeling).

Comment: @TinyGiant "Researched" does not mean only searched for on SO.

Comment: @Tom IMO, SO is quite good for trivial answers to trivial answers (though I think the post in this case probably had a dupe somewhere). The problem with the "hard" stuff is, as an asker, it's a long shot (it's more likely you'll just get the tumbleweed badge), as an answerer, it's harder to answer well, and as a searcher, I might not trust the answer, because it's harder to be sure if it really applies to me, or if it's rigorously tested. Also low research effort questions (e.g., "How do I send a TCP packet using <X>") can provide useful and easy hints, and a place to start.

Comment: @philipxy Yes it does. It doesn't matter if the answer can be found elsewhere on the internet, or most of Stack Overflow would be off-topic. I mean, most pure JavaScript questions can be answered by reading the language specification, MDN, or W3C standards documents, which would mean that all such questions would be off-topic, and the same could be said for many languages, frameworks, libraries, and such; but they aren't, and that's a good thing.

Comment: @TinyGiant Read [ask].

Comment: @philipxy The only mention of research on that page is: "Even if you don't find a useful answer ***elsewhere on the site***, including links to ***related questions that haven't helped*** can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest." (emphasis mine). So how's about _you_ read "How to Ask" before trying to educate me about what is said there.

Comment: Keep in mind that the purpose of that advice is to preempt duplicate closure, as evinced by the latter half of that sentence, _not_ to tell users that if the answer to their question could possibly be found somewhere in the far reaches of the internet then their question is off-topic.